# Multiple delete using Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I have Controller method which accepts List for multiple delete

```
[HttpPost]
public void DeleteAsync(List<int> ids)
{
}
```

How do I call this method from Backbone? can I have something like below?

```
var someView = backbone.View.extend({
    el: '',
    selectedArray: [],
    render: function () {},
    multipleDelete: function () {
        // here i want to do something like below
        selectedArray.destroy("/MyController/Delete");
        //or somthing like 
        var someCollection=Backbone.Collection.extend();

        //Adding the selectedArray values to someCollection and calling destroy 
        //configuring the URL
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Shubh, can you explain why you are mixing what appears to be java with javascript? Am I missing something? Please elaborate..

Comment: @jhohlfeld, he is not mixing, he has put the code of the server (apparently C#) and the code of the client (javascript)

Comment: @Markinhos your absolutely correct. Its C# code syntax with backbone.

Answer (score 0):

By default Backbone expects a RESTful API, so when you call `MyCollection.remove(models)` it will tigger `DELETE /myapp/MyModel` as many times as models you pass in the parameters. If you want to make a batch delete operation, you need to make some extra work creating your own AJAX call, to the endpoint you want with the list of IDs you want to delete.